# Refresh Activity without Closing it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using this code in activity opened from notification, but whenever refresh button is pressed activity stops instead of restarting

```
  refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(getIntent());
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you check what finish() does?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? If you only want to refresh some data you may use LiveData with Observers?

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity to profile activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,  Profile.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Profile activity to set result

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("edittextvalue","value_here")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code:**

frist activity `finish();` then restart using `startActivity(getIntent());`

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
```